# document.getElementById("popup_upload").style.display='none not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i want to hide my popup window when i trying to upload non image file.but i click upload photo button in a popup box,shows a loading symbol and execution  stops at that statement.here is my code.in console i get an error popup_upload not defined.please give me a solution for this issue...thanks to all in advance

```
     function addAvathar() {

    $imgtype=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $imext=explode('.',$imgtype);
    $ext=end($imext);
    if(($ext!='gif')&&($ext!='jpeg')&&($ext!='png')&&($ext!='jpg'))
   {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("popup_upload").style.display = "none";alert("upload correct file type");</script>';

           exit();
   }
   else{
    $config['upload_path'] = './avatar/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024mb';
    $config['max_width'] = '3000';
    $config['max_height'] = '3000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

        $ve['data'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        $this->upload->data();
    }


    if ($this->input->post("submit")) {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');

        $fInfo = $this->upload->data();

        if ($fInfo['image_width'] > 600) {
            $src = './avatar/' . $fInfo['file_name'];
            $percent = 0.5;
            $width = $fInfo['image_width'];
            $height = $fInfo['image_height'];
            $newwidth = $width * $percent;
            $newheight = $height * $percent;

            // Load
            $thumb = ImageCreateTrueColor($newwidth, $newheight);
            $extention = $fInfo['file_ext'];

            // create new jpeg image based on the target sizes

            switch ($extention) {
                case 'jpg':
                    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                    $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                    break;
                default:
                    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
            }

            // Resize
            imagecopyresized($thumb, $img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

            imagejpeg($thumb, $src, 90);
        }

        $ban = array('id' => '', 'title' => $title);
        $this->db->insert('bannar', $ban);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.window.show_popup_crop("../../avatar/' . $fInfo['file_name'] . '")</script>';
    } else {
        $this->load->view('crop', array('edt' => $edit['result'], 'result' => $data['result']));
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want help with your Javascript, then show us the generated HTML file (from View/Source in the browser), not the PHP script.  That way all of us who know Javascript, but don't know how to run your PHP in our heads can see what is actually executing in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP script if you are using any HTML tags means you can run the javascript in PHP script like the following code.

```
echo "<div id='popup_upload'></div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('popup_upload').style.display = 'none';alert('upload correct file type');</script>";
```

then only the script can find out the mentioned id in the HTML lines. Better you can return the error message in PHP and show it in front-end HTML file.